# Как упростить выражение?

Tags: python, pandas, инспекция-кода

```
print(f"short_model - {df.short_model.nunique()}")
print(f"transmission - {df.transmission.nunique()}")
print(f"region - {df.region.nunique()}")
print(f"manufacturer - {df.manufacturer.nunique()}")
print(f"state - {df.state.nunique()}")
print(f"title_status - {df.title_status.nunique()}")
print(f"age_category - {df.age_category.nunique()}")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: надо писать в вопросе, какого упрощения вы хотите.

Answer (score 5):

Зачем так сложно.

```py
print(df.nunique())
```

Пример вывода:

```
transmission    63
region          67
manufacturer    64
state           66
title_status    61
age_category    65
dtype: int64
```

Если какие-то колонки не нужны, берёте `df[список_колонок].nunique()` или так `df.drop(columns=[список_колонок_которые_не_нужны]).nunique()`.

P.S. Ещё чуть красивее:

```py
print(df.nunique().to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'nqunique'}))
```

Вывод:

```
              nqunique
transmission        63
region              67
manufacturer        64
state               66
title_status        61
age_category        65
```

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что это упрощение:

```
for name in ['transmission', 'region', 'manufacturer', 'state', 'title_status', 'age_category']:
    print(f"{name} - {df[name].nunique()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_=[print(f"{column} - {df[column].nunique()}") for column in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
print(f"""
transmission - {df.transmission.nunique()}
region - {df.region.nunique()}
manufacturer - {df.manufacturer.nunique()}
state - {df.state.nunique()}
title_status - {df.title_status.nunique()}
age_category - {df.age_category.nunique()}
""")
```

Comment: Ну тут явно можно и повторение всего остального уменьшить, а не только `print`-ов )